# $filter not working in functions outside the controller

Tags: angularjs

I define my functions outside the controller. I want to use $filter in one of the functions. You can see that it works inside the controller ($scope.test1 works) but it doesn't find $filter function in doSomething. Please help me figure it out. If i move doSomething inside the controller it will work but i dont want to do that.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I6Om2LmTbhHXsd6LC9U9?p=preview)

```js
    angular.module('myapp',[])
    
        .controller('appController',['$scope','$filter',function($scope,$filter) {
    
        $scope.doSomething = doSomething;
    
        //WORKS
        $scope.test1 = $filter('filter')([{typeid:1},{typeid:2}], { typeid: 2 }, true);
        
        
        }]);
    
    
    function doSomething($filter) {
    
      //DOES NOT WORK  
      test2 = $filter('filter')([{typeid:1},{typeid:2}], { typeid: 1 }, true);
      alert(test2);
      
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`$filter` works inside the controller because of dependency injection (when you declared the controller, you also specified its dependencies, such as `$scope` and `$filter`) while the doSomething function does not.

My questions would be:

1) Why declare `doSomething` outside the controller?  Is it for re-use?

2) Where do you intend to call `doSomething`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgF2a5Arq6AnJzQwGeg0?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myapp',[])

    .controller('appController',['$scope','$filter',function($scope,$filter) {

    $scope.doSomething = function() {
      doSomething($scope, $filter);
    };

    }]);


function doSomething($scope,$filter) {

  $scope.name = 'hello world';

  $scope.result = $filter('filter')([{typeid:1},{typeid:2}], { typeid: 1 }, true);
  alert($scope.result);

}
```